# How are variables inside decorator functions accessing values outside their scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Here is a sample decorator:

```
def smart_divide(func):
   def inner(a,b):
      print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
      if b == 0:
         print("Whoops! cannot divide")
         return

      return func(a,b)
   return inner

@smart_divide
def divide(a,b):
    return a/b
```

If `func` is an object then how do the variables `a` and `b` get accessed from it?

Isn't it like trying to to do this?

```
def func(potato):
      print(y, x)
```

Is there a fundamental concept I am not getting? Is what is happening here part of some pattern in Python or is it a special case situation where `a` and `b` know were to look because it is a generator?

---

**Update**

New example from [another stack exchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/5424873)

```
def my_shiny_new_decorator(a_function_to_decorate):

    def the_wrapper_around_the_original_function():

        print("Before the function runs")

        a_function_to_decorate()

        print("After the function runs")

    return the_wrapper_around_the_original_function

def a_stand_alone_function():
    print("I am a stand alone function, don't you dare modify me")
```

Generators the manual way

```
a_stand_alone_function = my_shiny_new_decorator(a_stand_alone_function)
a_stand_alone_function()
```

Generators the proper way

```
@my_shiny_new_decorator
def another_stand_alone_function():
    print("Leave me alone")
```

According to the place where I got the new answer from the 'manual' way and the 'proper way' are the same .

I think this example may have caused me to get stuck as I was trying to extend it to when there were parameters involved.

I now realise that what I was imagining didn't make sense

I thought that the original code I posted was equivalent to this

```
divide = smart_divide(divide(a,b))
```

which if executed would look like this

```
def smart_divide(divide(a,b)):
   def inner(a,b):
      print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
      if b == 0:
         print("Whoops! cannot divide")
         return

      return func(a,b)
   return inner
```

But this would cause divide(a,b) to be executed right in the top line

in the new example 'a_stand_alone_function' did not have () on the end. Which means it was treated as an object.

So my idea of it looking like this `def smart_divide(divide(a,b)):` doesn't make sense because the function won't be treated as an object anymore

This leaves me confused as to how `smart_devide` get the information passed as a parameter.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. `func` is the function that you are decorating, and a and b are its parameters.

Comment: No, your decorator returns `inner` as _implementaion_ for `divide`. Thus you call the function `inner` when you execute `divide(1, 2)` for instance, and you have to respect the signature of `inner` (and `divide` as in your code).

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman. But func is passed into `smart_devide` not a & b. If a & b are not passed in how are they assessed.

Comment: `a` and `b` are passed to `inner` and not to `smart_divide`. `smart_divide` is a function accepting a function as parameter and returning a function as result.

Comment: @macmoonshine I appreciate your reply, unfortunately I don't seem understand the background concepts you are using. More specifically what is 'implementaion' and 'signature'?

Comment: @macmoonshine But I didn't think inner could access those variables as they are outside of its scope. Isn't it like doing this [link to code example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1f3xclfrmguv1q/Screen%20Shot%202017-11-19%20at%2011.22.14%20PM.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smart_divide` **doesn't** get `a` and `b` passed into it. It returns a function object (the `inner` function), and **that** function gets `a` and `b` passed into **it**.

You can see what's actually happening if you try this:

```
def smart_divide(func):
   print("I am running in smart_divide; func=", func)
   def inner(a,b):
      print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
      if b == 0:
         print("Whoops! cannot divide")
         return

      return func(a,b)
   print("I am returning from smart_divide")
   return inner

print("I am running at top level before declaring divide")

@smart_divide
def divide(a,b):
    return a/b

print("The name 'divide' now refers to", divide)

print("I am now going to call the divide function")
divide(1, 2)
```

This outputs:

> ```
> I am running at top level before declaring divide
> I am running in smart_divide; func= <function divide at 0x108ff2bf8>
> I am returning from smart_divide
> the name 'divide' now refers to <function smart_divide.<locals>.inner at 0x10565db70>
> I am now going to call the divide function
> I am going to divide 1 and 2
> ```

Answer (score 2):

No, your decorator returns `inner` as new implementaion for `divide`. Thus, you first call the function `inner` when your program executes `divide(1, 2)` for instance. Calls to `divide` have always to respect the signature of `inner` (and divide as in your code).

A function like

```
def divide(a, b):  # signature
    return a / b   # implementation or body
```

consists of two parts. The signature describes the parameters, and the implementation what the function does.

Your decorator will only modify the implementation of your function as follows:

```
def divide(a, b):                            # signature remains unmodified
    print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)  # implementation of inner
    if b == 0:
        print("Whoops! cannot divide")
        return
    return a / b                             # call to the original implementation of divide
```

The name and the signature of `divide` remains the same. Thus, the signature of `inner` matters, and not the signature of your decorator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I still feel like I don't understand. Your explanation that the decorator returns inner as the new implimentation for divide, doesn't seem to link into anything else I know about how python works. It also doesn't match how generators were explained to me which was that they are equivilent to `divide = smart_divide(divide(a,b))`

Comment: The last row of your decorator is `return inner` which returns the implementation of `inner`. The decorator replaces the implementation for `divide` with this returned value. You can prove that by letting your decorator returning something other than a function, say the value 1. When you call `devide` than, you will get the error _TypeError: 'int' object is not callable_, because the decorator has applied an integer to `devide` instead of a function.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for taking the time to clarify. I think I mostly get it now.  I still feel like the decorator function is manipulating data in a way that nothing else I know about in python does. e.i I feel like I am missing out of the general principle that this is exploiting.

Comment: Keep in mind that functions in Python are generally variables as well. In particular, you can assign them new values, e. g.: `divide = multiply` ... and the decoration gets "lost", if `multiply` wasn't decorated.